# Scrapy or BeautifulSoup to scrape links and text from various websites

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy, python-3.5

I am trying to scrape the links from an inputted URL, but its only working for one url (http://www.businessinsider.com). How can it be adapted to scrape from any url inputted? I am using BeautifulSoup, but is Scrapy better suited for this?

```
def WebScrape():  
    linktoenter = input('Where do you want to scrape from today?: ')
    url = linktoenter
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    if linktoenter in url:
        print('Retrieving your links...')
        links = {}
        n = 0
        link_title=soup.findAll('a',{'class':'title'})
        n += 1
        links[n] = link_title
        for eachtitle in link_title:
            print(eachtitle['href']+","+eachtitle.string)
    else:
        print('Please enter another Website...')
```

Comment: what do you mean it only works for the one url? What happens when you give it another one - an error or unexpected result? What was the other urls that you tried? Please give us some more information/

Comment: That site seems to have `class="title"` for all the links you are trying to access which is what your code relies on, is this the case for the other pages?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, no the other pages list all of their links with different class = " ", trying to find a way to put all <a class= " " > in a dictionary and have link_title=soup.findAll(new dictionary), so it can pull whatever the url lists their class as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a more generic scraper, searching for all tags and all links within those tags. Once you have the list of all links, you can use a regular expression or similar to find the links that match your desired structure.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

response = requests.get('http://www.businessinsider.com')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

# find all tags
tags = soup.find_all()

links = []

# iterate over all tags and extract links
for tag in tags:
    # find all href links
    tmp = tag.find_all(href=True)
    # append masters links list with each link
    map(lambda x: links.append(x['href']) if x['href'] else None, tmp)

# example: filter only careerbuilder links
filter(lambda x: re.search('[w]{3}\.careerbuilder\.com', x), links)
```

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
def WebScrape():
    url = input('Where do you want to scrape from today?: ')
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    title_tags = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'title'})
    url_titles = [(tag['href'], tag.text)for tag in title_tags]

    if title_tags:
        print('Retrieving your links...')
        for url_title in url_titles:
            print(*url_title)
```

out:

```
Where do you want to scrape from today?: http://www.businessinsider.com 
Retrieving your links...
http://www.businessinsider.com/trump-china-drone-navy-2016-12 Trump slams China's capture of a US Navy drone as 'unprecedented' act
http://www.businessinsider.com/trump-thank-you-rally-alabama-2016-12 'This is truly an exciting time to be alive'
http://www.businessinsider.com/how-smartwatch-pioneer-pebble-lost-everything-2016-12 How the hot startup that stole Apple's thunder wound up in Silicon Valley's graveyard
http://www.businessinsider.com/china-will-return-us-navy-underwater-drone-2016-12 Pentagon: China will return US Navy underwater drone seized in South China Sea
http://www.businessinsider.com/what-google-gets-wrong-about-driverless-cars-2016-12 Here's the biggest thing Google got wrong about self-driving cars
http://www.businessinsider.com/sheriff-joe-arpaio-still-wants-to-investigate-obamas-birth-certificate-2016-12 Sheriff Joe Arpaio still wants to investigate Obama's birth certificate
http://www.businessinsider.com/rents-dropping-in-new-york-bubble-pop-2016-12 Rents are finally dropping in New York City, and a bubble might be about to pop
http://www.businessinsider.com/trump-david-friedman-ambassador-israel-2016-12 Trump's ambassador pick could drastically alter 2 of the thorniest issues in the US-Israel relationship
http://www.businessinsider.com/can-hackers-be-caught-trump-election-russia-2016-12 Why Trump's assertion that hackers can't be caught after an attack is wrong
http://www.businessinsider.com/theres-a-striking-commonality-between-trump-and-nixon-2016-12 There's a striking commonality between Trump and Nixon
http://www.businessinsider.com/tesla-year-in-review-2016-12 Tesla's biggest moments of 2016
http://www.businessinsider.com/heres-why-using-uber-to-fill-public-transportation-gaps-is-a-bad-idea-2016-12 Here's why using Uber to fill public transportation gaps is a bad idea
http://www.businessinsider.com/useful-hard-adopt-early-morning-rituals-productive-exercise-2016-12 4 morning rituals that are hard to adopt but could really pay off
http://www.businessinsider.com/most-expensive-champagne-bottles-money-can-buy-2016-12 The 11 most expensive Champagne bottles money can buy
http://www.businessinsider.com/innovations-in-radiology-2016-11 5 innovations in radiology that could impact everything from the Zika virus to dermatology
http://www.businessinsider.com/ge-healthcare-mr-freelium-technology-2016-11 A new technology is being developed using just 1% of the finite resource needed for traditional MRIs
```